# increase status textview everytime moneynum variable is increased by 100?

Tags: java, android

alright so im making an android app, and basically everything is working fine expect the whole part about changing the status textview everytime "moneynum" is increased by 100. Heres my code:

```
package life.project;



import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
public class LifeActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ViewFlipper views;
int lifestatus=0;
TextView status;
Button main;
Button work;
TextView timer;
int moneynum=0;
int test=0;
Button GasStation;
Button Walmart;
Button Business;
TextView Moneycount;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    main=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    views=(ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    GasStation=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
    Walmart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button23);
    Business=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button33);
    Moneycount=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    timer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    status=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    work=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    new CountDownTimer(1200000, 60000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("Minutes remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 60000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            onPause();{
            Intent timerends=new Intent("com.life.project.timesup");
            startActivity(timerends);
            finish();
            }
        }
     }.start();
     main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            views.showPrevious();
        }
    });
     work.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            views.showNext();
        }
    });
        GasStation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                moneynum+=5;
                Moneycount.setText("Money:$ "+moneynum+" .00");
                if(moneynum==moneynum+100){
                    lifestatus+=1;
                    status.setText("Status: "+lifestatus);
                }
            }
        });
        Walmart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                moneynum+=10;
                Moneycount.setText("Money:$ "+moneynum+" .00");
                if(moneynum==moneynum+100){
                    lifestatus+=1;
                    status.setText("Status: "+lifestatus);
                }
            }
        });
        Business.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                moneynum+=20;
                Moneycount.setText("Money:$ "+moneynum+" .00");
                if(moneynum==moneynum+100){
                    lifestatus+=1;
                    status.setText("Status: "+lifestatus);
                }
            }
        });

}
}
```

and heres the part where its not working:

```
  Moneycount.setText("Money:$ "+moneynum+" .00");
                if(moneynum==moneynum+100){
                    lifestatus+=1;
                    status.setText("Status: "+lifestatus);
                }
```

so everytime moneynum is increased by 100 i want lifestatus to increase by one and go through the rest of the code. But the if statement isnt executing when i run the program, and i think its because i have the arguments of the if statement wrong..can someone figure out i could make this work? sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: How could that if statement ever work? If 100==(100+100)

Comment: i know its not working, im trying to find out a way to make it work.

Comment: like how could i change it to make the if statement execute everytime moneynum is increased by 100.

Comment: Do you need the final value of money sum?

Comment: im trying to make the if statement evaluate moneynum, and everytime money num equals 100, 200, 300..etc. it increased lifestatus by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
public .... LifeActivity
{
  int moneySum = 100;
....
....
}

public void moneyCount()
{
 if(moneynum>=moneySum)  // Morethan incase your using looking for when moneynum passes 100 mark not when it equal exactly 100
   {
                    lifestatus+=1;
                    status.setText("Status: "+lifestatus);
                    moneySum+=100;
   }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                moneynum+=20;
                Moneycount.setText("Money:$ "+moneynum+" .00");
                moneyCount();
```

Comment: when i put the method you showed me in my code i get this error? "Syntax error on token "int", @ expected" I cant figure out whats wrong with it, your code seem perfectly fine to me. And im sure im not putting it in another method so that cant be it.

Comment: sorry int is supposed to be void haha, but i still get the error.